# Print Special Characters Arrays - PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a function called draw_stars() that takes an array of numbers and echo out  *.

```
    For example:

    $x = array(4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 25);
    draw_stars(x) should print the following on the screen/browser:

    **** 
    ****** 
    * 
    *** 
    ***** 
    ******* 
    *************************
```

So far here's my code:

```
$x = array(4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 25);
        function draw_stars($items){
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                for($i=0; $i<=$item; $i++){
                    echo '* <br>';
                }
            }
        }

        $output = draw_stars($x);
        echo $output;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why print `<br>` after each star?

Comment: `function draw_stars($items){
            foreach ($items as $item) { echo str_repeat('*', $item), '<br />'; } }`

Answer (score 1):

out of the box

```
   <?php
       $x = array(4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 25);
       foreach($x as $num) {
          echo str_repeat("*", $num).'<br>';
       }
```

and this in a function

```
  <?php
       function draw_stars(array $x, $star='*', $newline='<br>') {
           $return = '';
           foreach($x as $num) {
             $return.=str_repeat($star, $num).$newline;
           }
           return $return;
       }
       $x = array(4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 25);
       echo draw_stars($x);
       echo draw_stars($x,'_'); // with an otherstring example
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you print a line break after each star, which is obviously wrong. Also, your function does not return anything. I have modified your code a bit---it should now work.

```
        $x = array(4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 25);
        function draw_stars($items){
            $out = "";
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                for($i=0; $i<=$item; $i++){
                    $out .= '*';
                }
                $out .= '<br>';
            }
            return $out;
        }

        $output = draw_stars($x);
        echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$x = array(4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 25);
function draw_stars($items){
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        for($i=0; $i<$item; $i++){
            echo '*';
        }
        echo '<br />';
    }
}

draw_stars($x);
?>
```

Here you go, also with the '<=' you're having, you'll always print 1 more start that you really want, because $i is starting on 0.
And you're at the moment printing a break after every start, wich should be after the line of starts is made.